# Desktop in Kubuntu lacks bars and quite everything after trying to apply Plymouth fix for proprietary drivers

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm running Kubuntu 13.10, my computer's graphics card is Nvidia GT 520. I tried to fix that Plymouth's problem with proprietary graphics driver using an old script I found on the internet (it was coded for Natty, now that I think about it I shouldn't have done it). I ran that script and rebooted my computer.

First incorrect behaviour I noticed was that Plymouth only displayed its text splash only on 1/4th of the screen, though when I pressed Esc key the logs were displaying correctly.

Main problem appeared when I logged in. All my desktop's windows lack menu bar, can't be closed with Alt-F4, and they don't appear on the taskbar.

I tried fixing it by reinstalling GRUB a few times, purging /etc/grub.d and /boot/grub, but only the text splash issue was fixed. How can I fix that?

[This is the script I used.](http://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/fix-plymouth-on-ubuntu-after-installing-nvidia-or-ati-proprietary-drivers-for-ubuntu-11-04-natty/)

Comment: What script did you run ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen http://paolobernardi.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/fix-plymouth-on-ubuntu-after-installing-nvidia-or-ati-proprietary-drivers-for-ubuntu-11-04-natty/

Comment: That is a horrible script, it over writes system files without making back ups and there is no function to un do these changes. In addition, I suspect there are some sections that do not do what the author intends as using single quotes will insert the variable name (for the resolution) rather then the contents of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will fix it, but ...

```
sudo apt-get purge v86d
```

As root, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` and remove the line `"uvesafb mode_option=$resolution mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap"`

As root, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash` and remove the line `"echo FRAMEBUFFER=y"`

Then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo update-grub2
```

That might fix the problem, assuming you purged and re-installed grub2 (looks if all the other files edited were grub files).

Comment: I already tried reverting what script did to the system, so yeah, I purged and re-installed grub and I edited those files you mention.

Comment: @Michcioperz and?

Comment: Did you rebuild your initramfs ?

Comment: Yes, I did it all. I tried again now, and it still doesn't help. I however noticed another detail that may be helpful - virtual screens are unavailable, and visual effects don't work, could this script affect Compiz somehow?

Comment: Try creating a new user. If KDE works when you log in as a new user, then my guess would be your config files (.kde) are corrupt. If it does not work, then I am not seeing any additional problem and I do not see how that script would affect compiz. Are you even running compiz with KDE ???

Comment: I created a new user, and the problem appears there too. About Compiz, I don't know. I consider switching to lubuntu-desktop so that I can work until I find a solution.

Comment: Oh, and I also noticed there is a problem with fonts in console, does it suggest anything? (In Byobu there is Ubuntu logo as Unicode sign, and it is now displayed as a Chinese letter)

Answer (score 0):

**You should read carefully what you are doing**, that article is for Natty or 11.04 which is 2.5 releases from the one you are using.

Let's dissect what the script did:

1. It installed `v86d` and `hwinfo` packages. Both can be removed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge autoremove v86d hwinfo
   ```
2. There are several lines added to several files around all the system.

   ```
   sudo sed -e 's/FRAMEBUFFER\=y/d' /etc\/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash
   sudo sed -e 's/uvesafb/d
   ```
3. Then it modifies `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d/10_linux`, you can recover the original files by reinstallation:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge autoremove grub-pc
   sudo apt-get install grub-pc
   ```

   **DO NOT REBOOT THE SYSTEM**
4. Run `sudo update-grub2` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`